# Custom form throws 'Cannot unset string offsets' error

Tags: 8, entities, forms

I'm trying to build a form for my custom entity and so far the form is looking pretty good. However, when I press the Save button I get this error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Cannot unset string offsets in Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase->extractFormValues() (line 367 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetBase.php).

Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase->extractFormValues(Object, Array, Object) (Line: 231)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityFormDisplay->extractFormValues(Object, Array, Object) (Line: 338)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm->copyFormValuesToEntity(Object, Array, Object) (Line: 304)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm->buildEntity(Array, Object) (Line: 159)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm->buildEntity(Array, Object) (Line: 190)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm->validateForm(Array, Object) (Line: 139)
Drupal\worklog\Form\WorklogForm->validateForm(Array, Object)
```

This is the code for the form:

```php
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if (!$form_state->has('entity_form_initialized')) {
      $this->init($form_state);
    }

    /* @var \Drupal\worklog\Entity\WorklogInterface $entity */
    $entity = $this->entity;

//    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
//
//    return $form;

    $form['customer'] = [
      '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
      '#target_type' => 'node',
      '#selection_handler' => 'worklog',
      '#selection_settings' => [
        'target_bundles' => 'klant',
      ],
      '#title' => $this->t('Customer'),
      '#default_value' => $entity->getCustomer(),
      '#weight' => 5,
    ];

    $form['date'] = [
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#title'=> $this->t('Date'),
      '#default_value' => $entity->getDate()->format('Y-m-d'),
      '#weight' => 10,
    ];

    $form['hours_worked'] = [
      '#type' => 'number',
      '#title' => $this->t('Hours worked'),
      '#default_value' => '',
      '#weight' => 15,
    ];

    $form['description'] = [
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => $this->t('Work description'),
      '#default_value' => $entity->getDescription(),
      '#weight' => 20,
    ];

    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
      'submit' => [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Save')
      ]
    ];

    return $form;
  }
```

As far as i can tell I'm not doing any weird things inside this code. The code also only seems to have a problem when it encounters the 'hours_worked' field which doesn't make sense to me.

This seems like a very specific issue and I haven't been able to find any solutions to this, so I hope anyone knows what to do. Thanks

Comment: Is this form class extending ContentEntityForm? Then you are ignoring the inherited parent method and start building the form from scratch, which probably needs a lot more code than you have so far.

Comment: You are correct, it does inherit from ContentEntityForm. All examples and documentation I have found only show the form declarations in the buildForm function, as I have them.  

Do you have any tips on building a form myself? If I call any method on the parent it will include all entity fields, which is not what I want. Declaring the form myself ensures that only those fields are available and no changes in other files will affect this form.  

Maybe I just missed something. It doesn't make sense to me that my form would cause a string offset error in any widgets.

Comment: If you want to build and submit the form yourself, then extend FormBase.